# New CRM Connection code causing errors

Tags: dynamics-crm

am trying to create a console application that connects to CRM 2016 (On Prem) using the 2016 SDK.

The below code fails. The conn.LastCrmError has the following details and the orgService is null.

**Unable to Login to Dynamics CRMOrganizationWebProxyClient is null OrganizationServiceProxy is null OrganizationWebProxyClient is null OrganizationServiceProxy is null.**

```
var connectionString = @"Url=http://xxxx/xxxx/; Username=xxxx; Password=xxxx;";
            CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
            IOrganizationService orgService = conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

The connection works when running old code, below, using the 2015 SDK

```
 var connectionString = @"Url=http://wxxxxx/xxxx/; Username=xxxxx; Password=xxxxx;";
            IOrganizationService orgService2 = new OrganizationService(CrmConnection.Parse(connectionString));
            var results = orgService2.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Unable to Login to Dynamics CRMOrganizationWebProxyClient is nullOrganizationServiceProxy is nullOrganizationServiceProxy is null
```

This exception in most cases is thrown when you can't connect to CRM instance. Are you sure your connection string is ok? [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608573.aspx) are connections strings described. Maybe lack of 'domain' attribute is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nha responded on 5 Jan 2018 9:58 AM 
on https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/241256

MS support resolution, by add this line in the code before you connect to CRM.

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; 
//need to add ref. System.Net dll

or
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the AuthType in the connection string:

```
AuthType=AD;
```